# Absolutely continuous probability distribution and its probability density

Tags: density-function, continuous-data

A [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) states:

> A random variable $X$ has density $f_X$, 
>   where $f_X$ is a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function...
>   $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$...
>   $f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_X(x)$

However, if I am sure that the range of $X$ is $\mathcal{R}$,
 is it possible to claim that $f_X(x)>0,\forall x \in \mathcal{R}$?  For example, if $X$ follows a normal distribution or logistic distribution.

In a textbook of probability written in Chinese, it was claimed that:

> The random variable $X$ is absolutely continuous if and only if 
>   there exists a Lebesgue-integrable function $f_X:\ \mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R_+}$ 
>   which satisfies $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}, P\{X\in B\}=\int_B f_X(x)dx$."

(Reference: Theorem 2.15 in p.57 of Kuo-Yung Yen 2012 Probability 2/e published by 
Department of Mathematics, National Cheng-Kung University, Tainan, Taiwan 
http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~library/e-book/Probability21.pdf)

The author did not give any proof for this claim, and he only mentioned that 
it can be referred to Royden, H.L. Real Analysis, 2nd ed., 1968. § 5.4. 
But I have no such version of that book. 
Though I read another version of Royden's Real Analysis, 
I am not sure which theorem or lemma should be used to prove it...

---

Why did the author claim that $f_X:\ \mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R_+}$, but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) claimed that $f_X$ is a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to prove in the second question, because the Chinese quotation is often taken as the *definition* of absolutely continuous. What definition are you starting from? As far as your first question goes, what do you mean by "takes values in $\mathcal{R}$ everywhere"? If it means the range of $X$ is all of $\mathcal{R}$, then counterexamples are easy to come by. For instance, taking $X=(2U-1)V^2$ where $V$ is standard Normal and $U$ is Bernoulli$(1/2)$, it is clear that $X=0$ is *possible* (it would arise when $V=0$) but nevertheless $f_X(0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample. However, can I claim that "$f_X(x)> 0\  a.e.$" for your counterexample? Actually, my concern is mainly "Why did the author claim that $f_X:\ \mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R_+}$, but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) claimed that $f_X$ is a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function?" (I edited the last paragraph in my post.)

Comment: What exactly is meant by "$\mathcal{R}_{+}$"? If it's the set of non-negative reals, then there's no difference at all between the author and the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Oh...I found that the definition of $\mathcal{R_+}$ is not the same as I thought...It seems to be "nonnegative real numbers including 0" according to p.6 of that book. So, such problem was just misunderstanding of notation...my fault.